# Update a full record in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, record, multiple-columns

```
CREATE TABLE EXAMPLE(
ID INT(10),
NAME VARCHAR(10),
PHONE INT(10));
```

I only know to update columns one by one as,

```
UPDATE EXAMPLE SET ID=20,PHONE=991 WHERE NAME='PERSONA';
```

How do I update the full record, ie all columns at once instead of writing a list like `SET ID=20,PHONE=991` separated by commas?
Note that I actually want to implement on a table with 15 columns.

using mySQL.

Comment: That's the SQL standard syntax, if you're using a specific RDBMS you may have better luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the correct syntax already. You just need to keep adding the columns separated by commas. There is no other way.

```
UPDATE EXAMPLE SET ID=20,PHONE=991 WHERE NAME='PERSONA';
```

Comment: Isn't that a bit long when using about 15 columns?
Does mySQL or Oracle have any special methods?

Comment: Typically you would write a Stored Procedure to handle the updates to a table. Then you just call that SP with the new values.